# Django-CMS toolbar disabled

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

It’s solved

I am making a site on djangoCMS and for a better view I disabled the the toolbar. Now I can't enable it or I can't find any option to do that.

Here the toolbar means DjangoCMS own toolbar, not the website's toolbar which I enable it from the template by inserting `{% cms_toolbar %}` & `{% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}`.

It's a silly thing but it is a frustration. I went to documentation, all they have talked about website's own toolbar and its customization.

Django version 2.2.12 and I am using Python 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used 127.0.01:8000/en/?edit and it worked. This is for the ones who might need the solution in case.

Thanx any way